# RTK Query API get req fails in deployed environment

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, github-pages

I have recently deployed a my-react-app project to github pages with the npm package gh-pages.

I have an RTK Query that doesn't work in the deployed environment but still works in my dev environment. below is the code for the RTK Query and then the code calling the query in the react component.

I was wondering what could be causing the error?

```js
    getUni: builder.query({
      query: country => ({
        url: `http://universities.hipolabs.com/search?country=${country}`,
      }),
      transformResponse: responseData => {
        const resConvert = responseData.slice()
          .sort((a, b) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name))
          .map(each => {
            return { ...each, id: nanoid() }
          });
        return universityAdapter.setAll(initialState, resConvert)
      }
    }) 
  })
```

```js
const {
  isFetching,
  isSuccess,
  isUninitialized,
  isError
} = useGetUniQuery(countrySearch, {
  skip
});
const allUni = useSelector(getAllUniversity);

if (isUninitialized) {
  universityData = < h1 > Use the drop down menu to generate all Post Secondary options withen your selection < /h1>
} else if (isError) {
  universityData = < h1 > Error fetching.Please refresh page < /h1>
} else if (isSuccess) {
  universityData = allUni.filter(uni => uni.name.toLowerCase().startsWith(uniSearch.toLowerCase())).map(uni =>
    <div key = {uni.id}
    className = {CardStyles.card} >
      <h2 className = '' > 
        {uni.name} 
      </h2>
      <a href = {uni.web_pages[0]} >
        {uni.web_pages[0]} 
      < /a> 
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Try change this to https http://universities.hipolabs.com/ it’s restricted to do calls from https to http

Comment: @antokhio yup you nailed it. Unfortunately, it's an unsecured API. Do you know if there is a way to bypass this protocol or an NPM package to address this particular issue?

Comment: If you are on next you can do fake api route and call http from there, other then that no idea really…

Comment: Think there are some header options but I doubt it would work on prod

Comment: You can try to make a fake subdomain with nginx and do a redirect in there

Comment: @antokhio Unfortunately this project isnt Next but I'll look into nginx and see what I can come up with. Thanks for all the help!